# MYSQL query - how to construct total for only ids that have a particular value in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the two following tables. **In ONE query**, how can I total the column TOTAL_TIME for only those VEHICLE_IDs that have a FEATURE_ID of 2 found in TABLE 2?
Thus in my case **the result of the query should be 2:30** as it would add 2:00 and 0:30 because those vehicles have a FEATURE_ID of 2.
**TABLE 1**
VEHICLE_ID   |   TOTAL_TIME
----------------+-----------------
       22         |         2:00
       25         |         2:30
       22         |         1:25
       28         |         0:30
       ........

**TABLE 2**
VEHICLE_ID   |   FEATURE_ID
----------------+-----------------
       22         |         2
       22         |         3
       23         |         1
       23         |         3
       25         |         1
       28         |         2
       ........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could try something like:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.total_time) FROM table1 as t1 
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.vehicle_id = t2.vehicle_id AND t2.feature_id = 2
```

Comment: +1. Technically speaking, this would misbehave if a given vehicle appeared multiple times with `feature_id = 2` in table 2, but the question makes that seem unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT SUM(TOTAL_TIME) 
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE VEHICLE_ID IN (SELECT VEHICLE_ID FROM TABLE_2 WHERE FEATURE_ID = 2)

Are you looking for overall total time for FEATURE_ID = 2? OR are you looking for total overall time for FEATURE_ID = 2 grouped by VEHICLE_ID?? That would be something like:

```
SELECT T1.VEHICLE_ID, SUM(T1.TOTAL_TIME) 
FROM TABLE_1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T2.VEHICLE_ID = T1.VEHICLE_ID AND T2.FEATURE_ID = 2
GROUP BY T1.VEHICLE_ID
ORDER BY T1.VEHICLE_ID
```

Comment: If you decide to do a join make sure you use LEFT JOIN since there each vehicle can have multiple features. Assuming that's what you're looking for.

Comment: This works Thanks! However, I accept tehlulz as the answer because he was first. Thx again.